# Reading large files in c++

Tags: c++, text-files, filestream, binaryfiles

Suppose I have a .txt file the size of 9 GB. And I only want to read the n'th MB. (I know what is n). But my computer has only 4GB of ram so I can't load all the file at once. I need to access different n's multiple times. What's the best way to do this (I don't know if the standart ifstream is able of doing this stuff).

Answer (score 2):

You want to "seek" in the file to a specified location.  In C++ using `ifstream` you use `seekg()`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/seekg/

For example:

```
char data[1024*1024];
ifstream in("myfile.txt");
in.seekg(450 * 1024 * 1024, ios_base::beg); // skip 450 MB
if (in.read(data, sizeof(data)) {
    // use data
}
```

Comment: Just remember that `char data[1024*1024]` will allocate 1MB on stack which could pose a problem depending on your stack size. For larger allocations it's better to use heap. To do that just change the line to `char * data= new char[1024*1024]`.

Comment: @JosipVujcic: I was with you until you used `new`.  In C++14 we can use `make_unique<char[]>(1024*1024)`; in C++98 `std::vector<char> data(1024*1024)`.

Comment: I just wanted to point out possible problems and give simple solution. I agree with you that using smart pointers (in C++14) is the best way to do it.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Why not always use a `std::vector<char>`, the smart pointer loses the size information?

Comment: @JosipVujcic: Vector is a simple solution.  Memory leaks are a simple problem.  I prefer not to give newcomers a footgun.

Comment: @Galik: Well, sometimes the size is a constant, as in this case.  There is no use storing it if it is known at compile time.  But sure, if it's variable, use a vector.

Answer (score 0):

Is your OS 64-bit? If so, try **mmap()**.

> On modern operating systems, it is possible to mmap (pronounced
>   “em-map”) a file to a region of memory. When this is done, the file
>   can be accessed just like an array in the program.
>
> This is more efficient than read or write, as only the regions of the
>   file that a program actually accesses are loaded. Accesses to
>   not-yet-loaded parts of the mmapped region are handled in the same way
>   as swapped out pages.
>
> Since mmapped pages can be stored back to their file when physical
>   memory is low, it is possible to mmap files orders of magnitude larger
>   than both the physical memory and swap space. The only limit is
>   address space. The theoretical limit is 4GB on a 32-bit machine -
>   however, the actual limit will be smaller since some areas will be
>   reserved for other purposes. If the LFS interface is used the file
>   size on 32-bit systems is not limited to 2GB (offsets are signed which
>   reduces the addressable area of 4GB by half); the full 64-bit are
>   available.
>
> Memory mapping only works on entire pages of memory. Thus, addresses
>   for mapping must be page-aligned, and length values will be rounded
>   up.

More info:

- https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/linux-system-programming/0596009585/ch04s03.html
- https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Memory_002dmapped-I_002fO.html